# Notepad++ move end of line to start of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

This one is kinda silly but what I have is this:

```
<a href="http://link.com">Title</a>
```

My objective is to make it look like this

```
Title</a><a href="http://link.com">
```

There is thousands of lines and .com can be many different variations.  I have searched stackoverflow and found some similar regexes but was unable to convert to work for me.  I am not wise with this stuff but I feel the following is close from what I have read on here:

```
Find: ^([^">]*)\s+(">.*)
Replace: \2 \1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this. Thanks

Comment: Find [`(<.*?>)([^<]*?)(<\/a>)`](https://regex101.com/r/dNWFq3/1) and Replace `\2\3\1`.

Comment: Its the beginning to format it to an xml string and I want the title at the start to stay clean with what I have existing.  Its music and videos I have on my server in an index.html format

Comment: there's no space in your example, hence `\s+` in your regex won't work

Comment: @Tushar Wow thats perfect Thanks so much :) I was struggling for hours

Comment: It's better submit your comment in Answer to accept it and move question from unsolved list. @Tushar

Comment: please mark Tushar's Answer as Accepted by clicking on grey icon if you accept his answer, or any other and new answers @BobbyPeters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use below regex in find

```
(<.*?>)([^<]*?)(<\/a>)
```

and replace it with

```
\2\3\1
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dNWFq3/1)

1. `(<.*?>)`: Match a tag and add it in first captured group. `.*?` will match any character other than newline lazily to satisfy the following regex part
2. `([^<]*?)`: Match anything that is not `<` and add in second captured group
3. `(<\/a>)`: Match `</a>` and add in third captured group.
4. `\n`: `\n` in the replacement part is used to refer to `n`th captured group.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Worked Perfect Thanks all :)  awesome bunch of helpful people here

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<a\b[^>]+>)(.+?/a>)`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(       : start group 1
  <a\b  : <a and a word boundary
  [^>]+ : 1 or more characters that is NOT >
  >     : >
)       : end group 1, it contains <a href.....>
(       : start group 2
  .+?   : 1 or more any character, not greedy
  /a>   : /a>
)       : end group 2, it contains the title and the close anchor tag.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this : `(<a href="[\w:\/\/\.]+">)(\w+)(<\/a>)` and in replace box textbox put `\2\1\3`.

For the explanation of regex : https://regex101.com/r/wFY4I3/1

Comment: You're writing regex for links that have no 'class' and 'style' and other properties and this matching is not useful.

Comment: You're right, i've just take his data example and create a regex to match with. With his example it works, but you're right, it's not generic.